# Maintain all unsaved changes after computeChangeSets in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following 2 entities:

- ProtectedEntity
- ProtectedEntityChangeRequest

The ProtectedEntityChangeRequest stores values that can be applied to the ProtectedEntity after undergoing an business approval process.

The values are applied to ProtectedEntity using an `EventSubscriber` that subscribes to the Doctrine event `onFlush`. As the ChangeRequest can be approved automatically or after receiving manual approval, the subscriber checks both `getScheduledEntityInsertions` and `getScheduledEntityUpdates`. The code is as follows:

```php
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args): void
{
    $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();
    $unitOfWork = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
        if (!($entity instanceof ProtectedEntityChangeRequest)) {
            continue;
        }

        // If needed, apply changes to ProtectedEntity

        $unitOfWork->computeChangeSets();
    }

    foreach ($unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        if (!($entity instanceof ProtectedEntityChangeRequest)) {
            continue;
        }

        // If needed, apply changes to ProtectedEntity

        $unitOfWork->computeChangeSets();
    }
}
```

This has a major flaw - if ProtectedEntity had any changes:

- in application code, prior to entering the `onFlush` subscriber;
- AND in the onFlush subscriber, before calling `computeChangeSets`

The old changes will be erased from the changeset and therefore won't be saved to the database. Note that if the entity hasn't changed within the onFlush subscriber, the old changes will remain after the `computeChangeSets` call. This brings me to my question:

**How do I maintain all unsaved changes when calling computeChangeSets?**

The application runs on Symfony 6.2.6 and PHP 8.2. Thanks in advance for your help!

---